# Why do we have separate Spliterators class in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why did new `Spliterators` class appear in Java 8? Since Java 8 we have possibility to add `static` methods to the interfaces.
Since `Spliterators` class has only static method wouldn't be simpler to declare all its methods in the `Spliterator` `interface`?

The same question about `Collectors/Collector` pair.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

It’s perfectly possible that this decision was made without even thinking about this brand new possibility, but simply following the established-since-twenty-years pattern.

Besides that, it can be debated whether it is really useful to add 25 to 30 `static` methods to an interface. It makes sense to offer a few factories for canonical implementations, but you should draw a line somewhere. It’s not feasible to add factories to *all* implementations to an interface, just because they are offered by the same library. But this debate would be off-topic.

Further, `Spliterators` does not only offer `static` methods, but also nested classes. Unlike `static` methods, these classes would pollute the name space of every implementation class, when being defined in an `interface`.

`Collectors` and `Spliterators` may also contain implementation-specific non-`public` methods and even fields.

Comment: the reasoning about pollution is what i liked most in your answer. 1+

Answer (score 2):

No, is not good idea, because `interface` declares a contract, but class represents logic. But after add `default` method to `interface` in Java 8 we can only declare `public` method, but in abstract class we can add `public` and `private` abstract method, so we still can hide some logic in abstract classes. Imagine, in actual level of language you can declare only `public` method, and everyone can change your idea for e.q. `Collection`

Comment: I agree, and i would add : see the *"SOLID"* principle, It would broke both the *S*:Single responsibility principle and the *I* Interface segregation principle

Comment: Note : private methods are allowed in interface since 9

Comment: Yes, bat now Java 8 is main language level :)

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a difference between an interface and a class. These two have different intentions. Interface declares a contract. Default methods for the interface should be used carefully, for instance, where you can't break compatibility by adding a method declaration into an interface and can't declare xxxV2 interface.

A class is an entity, which represents a unit of the program logic.